# How Can I Add An Item To Folders Menu Of Right Click?

Tags: windows, winforms, delphi, delphi-7

I need to add an item to folders right click menu when clicked send folder address to my app. how can i do it? it'll be a great help if you describe how to make popup menu for that item and how can i use images for items? something like [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/).... and what about file types? same ways?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add new options to the right-click context menu, you'll need to set it up as a shell extension and register it with Windows.  [Here's an article describing the basic principles for it](http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc071701a.htm).

As for how to register a file type with Windows, you can find a mimimal but well-commented Delphi example [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/13393).

Comment: is there any component or some easier way to do that? i googled but nothing found

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is create a Shell Extension. A starting point is this article: [Delphi: Windows Shell Extensions](http://www.prestwoodboards.com/aspsuite/kb/document_view.asp?qid=100189). Essentially you need to create a COM component that implements [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28VS.85%29.aspx), [IContextMenu2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776091%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [IContextMenu3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776086%28VS.85%29.aspx) and expose it to Explorer by registering it appropriately.

There's an example at delphi3000.com, but it's only available via the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:P5QukHGHEy4J:www.delphi3000.com/article.asp%3FID%3D2926+shell+extension+context+menu+delphi&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a) at present.

Comment: In case the OP is unaware, if the target OS is 64-bit versions of Windows, Delphi only produces 32-bit binaries which won't work.

Comment: is there any component or some easier way to do that? i googled but nothing found

Comment: @Armin, not that a cursory search uncovered. Writing Explorer add-ins is quite a specialised task so you'll probably have to take the hit and write it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Delphi, you may still be able to use the TurboPower ShellShock components http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpshellshock/ to make your life a bit easier :)

Comment: Thanks. It was a great package. but i couldnt find what i need in any of this package components. can you tell me wich component provide my need?

Comment: Well, it's not directly relevant to answering your question, sorry. Just that the package has lots of good code pertaining to using Shell-related stuff that I thought could make your life easier :-)